# A redundant standalone backup solution for a small amont of information

Tags: backup, raid

Currently a software vendor suggests storing backups of their software's database (that includes confidential and private information) on flash drives on a regular basis. Having had my share of pain with USB drives I see this as highly problematic and dangerous solution.
What if the drive suddenly becomes unreadable or even lost/damaged? Would not want to risk this. I am just bystander in this case (no connection to the vendor), but I find their solution highly problematic considering the importance of the data being stored.

The amount of data is really small (considering the fact that it can fit on a 2GB-4GB flash drive). An ideal solution would do redundancy checks (some form of RAID?), and would be a ready made product that I can just buy and setup.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data set is that small can you not store it on a file server that you may already have and include it in that backup? Also if this file server is set up correctly you would have a RAID array on this as well.